# Run generated jar file in apache flink

Tags: macos, apache-flink

At the moment I'm trying to run my first flink application. I already tested the java file (KMeans.java) in the IDE and it works perfectly but I can't handle to get this java file run as an jar in command line.
The build was successfully created with `mvn clean package`.
But if I run my jar file in command line `flink run -c KMeans name.jar`
this error message appears:

> The program finished with the following exception:

> org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The
> program's entry point class 'KMeans' was not found in the jar file.
> at
> org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.loadMainClass(PackagedProgram.java:617)
> at
> org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.(PackagedProgram.java:199)
> at
> org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.buildProgram(CliFrontend.java:856)
> at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:206)
> at
> org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1044)
> at
> org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$11(CliFrontend.java:1120)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
> javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)    at
> org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1754)
> at
> org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41)
> at
> org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1120)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: KMeans   at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
> java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
> java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)   at
> org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.loadMainClass(PackagedProgram.java:614)
> ... 10 more

So I looked up my generated target folder and there is a KMeans.class file in the classes folder. So I'm doing this wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the full class name, e.g., `org.apache.flink.examples.java.clustering.KMeans`.

Note that you only need to use the -c flag if the JAR file doesn't specify the class to run in its manifest.